# Child function not accessible when called from parent component through ref in React.js when placed in separate files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference

I have three components Parent A and two sub-component Child B and Child C in react.js.

```
FileA:

class Parent extends React.component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childForA = React.createRef();
    this.childForB = React.createRef();
    this.CallingFunctionForA = this.CallingFunctionForA.bind(this);
    this.CallingFunctionForB = this.CallingFunctionForB.bind(this);
  }
  CallingFunctionForA = () => {
    this.childForA.current.CallFunctionInA(); // function is available
  };
  CallingFunctionForB = () => {
    console.log(this.childForB); // no functions  available through references
    this.childForB.current.CallFunctionInB(); //not accessible will give undefined
  }


      render(){
              return(
                     <div>
                     <ChildA ref={this.childForA} callFuncB={this.CallingFunctionForB.bind(this)}>
                     <ChildB ref={this.childForB} callFuncA={this.CallingFunctionForA.bind(this)}>
                     </div>
              );
      }

 }


class childA extends React.Component{

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 }
 ComponentDidMount = () =>{
     this.props.callFuncA();
 }
   CallFunctionInA =() =>{
    console.log("In A");
  }

}



File B:

const styles = theme => ({
root: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
},
formControl: {
  margin: theme.spacing.unit*2+4,
  minWidth: 120,
},
selectEmpty: {
  marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
},
buttonSuccess: {
  backgroundColor: blue[500],
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: blue[700],
  },
},
fabProgress: {
  color: blue[500],
  position: 'absolute',
  top: -6,
  left: -6,
  zIndex: 1,
},
buttonProgress: {
  color: blue[500],
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  marginTop: -12,
  marginLeft: -12,
   },
  });

class childB extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);

   }
   ComponentDidMount = () =>{
     this.props.callFuncB();
   }
    CallFunctionInB =() =>{
    console.log("In B");
  }
}
export default (withStyles(styles))  (childB);
```

When the function in childB is called it is inaccessible from the parentA, but the functions in childA is called it is accessible. Why references are not available from children component in different files, but accessible from children component in same file ?

Comment: Why do you want to keep ChildA and parent component in same file !!

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G  I don't want to keep but if I don't keep them in same file, I am unable to access the child functions from parent component through reference

Comment: Looking at your code i think you want to call childA function from childB and childB function from ChildA right ? thats the reason why you creating ref in parent and exchanging the handlers right ?

Comment: Yes exactly, some update in childA should trigger another function in childB and vice-versa

Comment: Have you imported ChildB in Parent

Comment: @GauravSaraswat yes I have imported the ChildB in parent and I am able to see the props I am passing from Parent to ChildB, just the functions inside childB does not show up alongwith the reference.

Comment: I have a demo with proper exports and imports. please check in my answer below.

Comment: @GauravSaraswat thanks a lot I was looking for this only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some problem in the way you are **exporting** your `childB component`.

I just made a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zjz38lolj) for you. Please check and comment if it solves your error.

Comment: I am exporting exactly the same way as you did in the demo the difference being I am exporting alongwith some formatting styles as shown in material-ui demo here.(https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/)

Comment: Just a quick question, why if I export like I did with styles, the refernce is not passed, but if the export is done inline alongwith the declaration of function the reference is passed.

Comment: I dont think, there is anything wrong with that too `withStyles()` returns a . HOC. right? You need to pass `innerRef` in the options(which is second argument). [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component)

Comment: yes withStyles() returns an HOC but I am unable to import alongwith the ref using the innerRef parameter as there is no example I found to implement that

Comment: please do like this: `<childB innerRef={this.childForA}...`

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a binding problem

```
 class Parent extends React.component {
    const CallingFunctionForA = () => {...}
    const CallingFunctionForB = () => {...}

      render(){
              return(
                     <div>
                     <ChildA callFuncB={CallingFunctionForB}>
                     <ChildB  callFuncA={CallingFunctionForA}>
                     </div>
              );
      }

 }


class childA extends React.Component{
 ComponentDidMount = () =>{
     this.props.callFuncA();
 }
  const CallFunctionInA =() =>{
    console.log("In A");
  }

}
File B:

class childB extends React.Component{
   ComponentDidMount = () =>{
     this.props.callFuncB();
   }
   const CallFunctionInB =() =>{
    console.log("In B");
  }
}
export (childB);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are trying to achieve communication between two components

To achieve this I would not recommend creating a `ref` and exchanging handlers like this, `ref` shouldn't be used here.

> Solution :

Whenever you want that change in **ChildA** Component has to trigger some piece of code in **ChildB** Component then we have to solve this in **React** way, you need to do a **level up**, your parent component has to be informed about the change in **ChildA** and that change need to travel to **ChildB** via `props` from **Parent Component**.

Have **State** in Parent Component also have a **handler** which updates that **state** in Parent Component and pass that down to **ChildA** has a `prop`

```
    class Parent extends React.component {
          constructor(){
           this.state = {
              someInformation : false;
            }
          }

          updateSomeInformation = () =>{
            this.setState({someInformation : true});
          }

          render(){
                  return(
                         <div>
                         <ChildA someInformation={this.state.someInformation} 
                         updateSomeInformation={this.updateSomeInformation}/>
                         <ChildB someInformation={this.state.someInformation}  
                         updateSomeInformation={this.updateSomeInformation}>
                         </div>
                  );
          }

        }
```

Comment: But this method doesn't work, where should I initialize the state component inside childB with the props, if the binding is done inside constructor then subsequent changes in props is not reflected in the local state variable of childB Component.

Comment: State will reside in your parent component, ChildA and ChildB will update parent component so that the other child will be informed when there is a change.